# Conditional textline avoiding a whiteline when no text is printed

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm writing a script that creates custom pdf-reports for a few hundred teams. Based on the data per team the code chooses what advice and how many pieces of advice to print in the PDF-file for this specific team. I'm able to print different advice per team, or print no advice if there is none, but I fail to prevent him printing the line-end.

The code below will only print the header and advice when it is relevant, but it will always print a empty lines.

```
When 6 is not relevant this line should be directly followed by the fourth line of this example  
### `r if(params$df$relevant[6]){params$df$Heading[6]}`
`r if(params$df$relevant[6]){params$df$Advice[6]}`
When 6 is not relevant this line should directly below the first line of this example, without white lines in between
```

In my workflow I start in R which imports and analyses data for all teams. Per team it calls `rmarkdown::render()` to open a template .RMD/RMarkdown file, sending the advice text in a df via the parameters from the R-script to the template.

A brief description of other strategies I tried and failed with (and which would warrant a new question if the current one is a dead end?):

- pre-format the text in R. That looks good in R, but the formatting gets ignored when printed to PDF by Rmarkdown. So I don't get line ends between the advices I do want to print
- print the text within an R-code chunk. That will print the correct text, but I cannot get the R-code chunk to use the same font as the rest of the document.
- use the `ifelse()` function instead. That doesn't seem to create a Header if you type `###` in front of the row
  ...you can imagine my shame for being stumped by an if-statement...

I'm new to this forum. Please let me know if I can phrase the question more clearly without giving irrelevant info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Not sure if there's a simpler approach but in similar situations I like to avoid markdown and inline R code and instead wrap it up in a code chunk (which also makes control flow easier):

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=F}
a <- "When 6 is not relevant this line should be directly followed 
by the fourth line of this example"
b <- "When 6 is not relevant this line should directly below the 
first line of this example, without white lines in between"

if(params$params$df$relevant[6]) {
  cat(a, paste0('\\subsubsection{', params$df$Heading[6], '}'), b)
} else {
  cat(a, "\\newline", b)
  }
```
````

(`\subsubsection` and `\newline` are LaTeX commands for level-three heading and linebreak, respectively.)

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the late reply, I sadly only have one R day. I hope my delay didn't feel ungrateful.
I agree the control flow is easier in a code chunk. So far my problem there was that the font didn't conform to the rest of the document. I think you solved that problem as well, but I'm still experimenting what exactly in your code does the trick. It seems to be a combination of the `results = 'asis'` setting and the `cat()` and `paste0()` functions. I succeeded in getting the Header right, but I'm still working on the normal text afterwards and will continue on that next week.

Comment: Thanks again Martin I got it to work and figured out a bit why you need the functions in this order. The `paste0()` concatenates it AND converts the content to string, `cat()` concatenates is again and prints where the LaTeX-commands are implemented. Previously I used the `print()` function, but that doesn't get the LaTeX-commands implemented. The `message()` function does get the LaTeX-commands implemented but changes the font.
It didn't matter in this case if I used `paste0()` or just `paste()`
Not using `results='asis'` caused not implementing  LaTeX-commands and using a different font

Comment: Sry, forgot to reply to your first comment but I'm glad the solution suits your needs!